# PHP recursive multidimensional loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, recursion, multidimensional-array

```
$printArr = recursive($newArray); //calls recursive function
$data = [];
var_dump($data);
var_dump($printArr);
    function recursive($array, $level = 0)
    {
        $searchingValue = 'tableName';
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
                //If $value is an array.
                if(is_array($value))
                {
                    recursive($value, $level + 1);
                } 
                else
                {
                    //It is not an array, so print it out.
                    if($key == $searchingValue)
                    {
                        echo "[".$key . "] => " . $value, '<br>';
                        $data[] = $value;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

So I have this function and I am trying to save $value value into $data[] array. But it always returns it empty and I don't know why I can't get $value saved outside the function.
If i echo $value I get what i need but like I've mentioned the variables doesn't get saved in this case - table names.

Comment: Have you called `recursive()` function anywhere? Or just declared and printed `$data` array which is already blank.

Comment: What purpose does `$level` serve?

Comment: Can you explain the goal of the function which you have written?

Comment: Or even show some sample input and both actual vs. expected output

Comment: Yes I did. 
$printArr = recursive($newArray); //calls recursive function
$data = [];
var_dump($data);
var_dump($printArr);
I've also added in the question code.

Comment: You set `$data` to an empty array - then you immediately dump `$data`.  Of course, it's empty.  On the first line, you call `recursive($newArray)` but you haven't shown us what the contents of `$newArray` look like.  Without knowing what you are passing *into* your function, it's hard to test how/if it works.  You reference `$data` inside your recursive function, *but you never pass it into the function*.

Comment: You say that the function "always returns it empty", but the code you've shown doesn't return **anything**.  Because there is NO `return` statement in your function, the value of `$printArr` will always be `NULL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the $data to your recursive function.  Also you need to return the $data.

Try this code :

```
function recursive($array, $level = 0, $data =[])
{
    $searchingValue = 'tableName';
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
            //If $value is an array.
            if(is_array($value))
            {
                recursive($value, $level + 1 , $data);
            } 
            else
            {
                //It is not an array, so print it out.
                if($key == $searchingValue)
                {
                    echo "[".$key . "] => " . $value, '<br>';
                    $data[] = $value;
                }
            }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: If you pass by reference, you dont need to return data, choose one. Also, you are not passing data by reference in example.

Comment: It worked! I can't believe I didn't think to pass  reference. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access variable $data, which is outside the function, from the function. You need to pass it by reference or return it. Small example

```
<?php

$a = 1;

// Your case
function b() {
    $a = 4;
    return true;
}
// Passing by reference
function c(&$d) {
    $d = 5;
    return true;
}
// Using return
function d($d) {
    $d = 6;
    return $d;
}

b();
var_dump($a);

c($a);
var_dump($a);

$a = d($a);
var_dump($a);
```

https://3v4l.org/UXFdR